# L-value to R-value conversion

Tags: c, expression, lvalue-to-rvalue

the site here says that:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc05lvalue.htm

```
If an lvalue appears in a situation in which the compiler expects an rvalue, 
the compiler converts the lvalue to an rvalue.

An lvalue e of a type T can be converted to an rvalue if T is not a function or        
array type. The type of e after conversion will be T. 

Exceptions to this is:

    Situation before conversion             Resulting behavior

1) T is an incomplete type                  compile-time error
2) e refers to an uninitialized object      undefined behavior
3) e refers to an object not of type T      undefined behavior
```

---

**Ques.1:**

Consider following program,

```
int main()
{   
    char p[100]={0};      // p is lvalue
    const int c=34;       // c non modifiable lvalue

    &p; &c;               // no error fine beacuse & expects l-value
    p++;                  // error lvalue required  

    return 0;
}
```

My question is that why in expression `(p++)`  `++(postfix)` expects `l-values` and arrays are `l-value` then why this error occurs?
**gcc error: lvalue required as increment operand|**

**Ques.2:**

Plzz explain the `exception 3` with an `example`?

Comment: the address of the array(static) is not a l-value.

Comment: I don't understand how your question (#1) relates to the passage that you quote.  The use of postfix `++` does not involve a conversion from lvalue to rvalue.

Comment: @nickie when i compile this statement p++ i get the compile  time error from gcc

Comment: Yes, of course, @cnicutar explained this below.  It's just the title of your question that is not accurate, I think.  There's no conversion between lvalues and rvalues involved.

Comment: @nikie what is the type of p in p++ sir could you please elaborate why the error is coming what is exactly happening here when evaluating p++

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are indeed lvalues, but they are not modifiable. The standard says:

> 6.3.2.1
>
> A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type

Comment: Also, 6.5.2.4, the operands to a postfix `++` shall be a modifiable lvalue.  Your `p` is not a modifiable lvalue, as correctly answered.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to question 2.

Say you have an object of type `double`.  You take a pointer and cast it to a different pointer type.  Then you use the new pointer to dereference the object.  This is undefined behavior.

```
double x = 42.0;
double *p = &x;
int *q = (int *) p;

*q;
```

Here, `*q` is an lvalue of type `int` which does not refer to an object of type `int`.